# In Google Script Copy and paste reference is not working when recording macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macros

When recorded below macro it works ok but with just one problem that I want *Calender!D6* to be variable which is coming from second line of code *spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();*.

Problem that when macro is recorded it is picking same cell no matter what cell I am selecting while running the macro. Please help

---

```
function Enqq_8() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dumpp'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Calender!D6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Calender'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-4, 5).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dumpp'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Calender!J2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]&R[-2]C[0]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 3).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=Vlookup(R[1]C[-3],Data!C[10]:C[11],2,0)');
};
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet with your expected output, and define the goal that you would like to achieve and possibly a use case explanation?

Comment: `I want Calender!D6 to be variable` "**I want**" is not a description of a problem. Also, you have not described the purpose of the script/macro, not its use, nor whether the sheet or cell is to be the variable, nor how it is expected that the variable value can be identified. Please edit your question to explain the script in detail, how you expect that variables to be identified, and also show what you have done to resolve the "problem" yourself.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz

Much apologies I did not explained my problem clearly, That cell "Calender!D6" was the cell from where I was picking the Date to use in vlookup formula and I needed it to be currently selected cell. I did it by defining the variable which I am pasting below.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code which worked

```html
function Raw_Filter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sss = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raw_View'), true);
  sss.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0).activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Calender!J2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[0]&R[-2]C[0]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-3, 3).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Raw_Data!A1:N1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=FILTER(Raw_Data!C[-3]:C[10],Raw_Data!C[-3]:C[-3]=R[1]C[-3],Raw_Data!C[1]:C[1]=R[0]C[-3])')
};
```